# YII - renderPartial gives error with CActiveForm

Tags: yii

I am trying to include form on product page using renderPartial but it gives error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getErrors() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php on line 1605

i am using below code...

in product page

```
// product detail goes here, use below form to make an inquiry about this product
<?php $this->renderPartial('inquiry'); ?>
```

and in inquiry page page

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'query-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>


    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a variable called `$model` in your view, but in your controller's `renderPartial()` call, you are not passing `$model` into your view.  So the view is looking for a variable called `$model`, but it does not exist.

You need to generate a new model in your controller, then pass it into the view, as follows:

```
$model = new Product(); //use whatever class you created for the model in place of 'Product' here

$this->renderPartial('inquiry', array('model'=>$model));
```

The `'model'=>$model` tells Yii to pass the variable `$model` into the view, and the `'model'` represents the name you use to access that variable from within the view.  So if you write something like:

```
$this->renderPartial('inquiry', array('product'=>$model));
```

Then in the view, you would access the variable by typing `$product` instead of `$model`.